# Java sqlite computing students number in every month

Tags: java, mysql

Hello Programmers i hope you solve my problem. i want to compute every students absent in every month. example Angelo Gabarda | 3 absents in june. like that. im using java DB sqlite for my data base and im using Eclipse.

Here is my video in my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0o-zCYI84I 
and if you want to download my java codes source from eclipse: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HtkYxeVGkzGb6EQidbEQS7wRuExIjCbA

Comment: No one will download your source code. You need to post your code here at own.

Comment: image 1:   https://ibb.co/cDXSrz
 Image 2 : https://ibb.co/b3KU4K

Comment: Seriously? You want me to go view videos and and download code? Much better if you explain the problem in the question include sample data as text in the question and include code as text in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Help us help you - please share your table(s) definition, some sample data and the result you want to get for it, **as text**.

Comment: While links can be nice as *additional* info, they can't be *only* info about your problem since if links break question becomes unclear. Also don't post code as image ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to clarify your question.

Comment: i cant post image whyy??

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't provided details about your tables and column names, Let's assume your table name is Student and it has name column and date_absent column of type date, then you basically need following type of query that will give you in result, name, month and number of times absent in that month. Try using this query in your code.

```
select name,date_format(date_absent,'%Y-%M') as month, count(1) as numberOfTimesAbsent from Student group by name, month;
```

This query will give you something like this.

```
+-------------------+-------------+---------------------+
| name              | month       | numberOfTimesAbsent |
+-------------------+-------------+---------------------+
| Anurag Gupta      | 2018-August |        3            |
| Anurag Gupta      | 2018-July   |        2            |
| Anurag Arora      | 2018-August |        2            |
| Anurag Arora      | 2018-July   |        4            |
+-------------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: can u do that for me please>??

Comment: here is my code: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HtkYxeVGkzGb6EQidbEQS7wRuExIjCbA

Comment: can u do that for me??

Comment: Dear @AngeloGabarda I can definitely help you complete your program but that way you won't learn much. Like I have given you pointers how to proceed with what you want to achieve, you should go ahead and try yourself. I can further give you pointers again when you are stuck. Moreover, I haven't got a chance to program in java swings.

Comment: plssss im a beginner asjdasjdkasdas

Comment: plsss pleaseeee if you tell me i can read that so i can learn

Comment: ok add my skype id pkr555 and lets take it offline and not bother others :)

Comment: im stuckkk since sept 13, 2018

Comment: Ok your program is done. When you run you will see a window like this with the information you wanted. Image link here https://ibb.co/b6HM4K Right now I have harded the data, so you will have to comment few lines and uncomment lines that will pick data from database. Add me on Skype so I can send you code there.

Comment: send on GDRIVE oki

Comment: can we video chat on facebook. add me on face book Name is Angelo Gabarda